# Callback on variable change in python

Tags: python, events, concurrency

I've searched around but didn't find anything like this. Let's say I have an army of threads, that keep reading and updating an integer variable `x`. I would like a callback for when `x` changes over a certain margin, let's say 500, to run the callback.

How can this be done without putting a heavy load on the system, like having a thread that has a `while true` and checks if the variable has changed?  Performance is critical. But so are ethics.

In plain code would be something like this:

```
x = 10
def runMe():
    print('Its greater than 500!!') 

def whenToRun():
    return x >= 500

triggers.event(runMe, whenToRun)
```

Comment: Does `x` have to be a global variable, or it can be, say, an attribute of some object?

Comment: You can either "hide" the variable behind a setter which takes care of notifying the observers, or (if that is in no way doable), you can go for the suboptimal option of having a thread which constantly checks the value in the variable.

Comment: `x` will be an attribute of some object

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, you _can_ do. One way is through debugger hooks, which may be too slow. Alternatively, you can use your `__setitem__`-hooked container as a module dict, either in a hacky way, or with a nice import hook that gives all `.py` files your custom dict subclass. Maybe other ways as well.

Answer (score 32):

You want to have a function (a  *"setter"*) which is called whenever the variable's value changes. A good way to do that is to define a `@property`. It will behave like a variable, but will have a *getter* function and a *setter* function.

Then, in the *setter*, call any callbacks you need, which will react to the change.

This should do the trick:

```
class ObjectHoldingTheValue:
    def __init__(self, initial_value=0):
        self._value = initial_value
        self._callbacks = []

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        old_value = self._value
        self._value = new_value
        self._notify_observers(old_value, new_value)

    def _notify_observers(self, old_value, new_value):
        for callback in self._callbacks:
            callback(old_value, new_value)

    def register_callback(self, callback):
        self._callbacks.append(callback)
```

Then, you can do:

```
def print_if_change_greater_than_500(old_value, new_value):
    if abs(old_value - new_value) > 500:
        print(f'The value changed by more than 500 (from {old_value} to {new_value})')

holder = ObjectHoldingTheValue()
holder.register_callback(print_if_change_greater_than_500)
holder.value = 7    # nothing is printed
holder.value = 70   # nothing is printed
holder.value = 700  # a message is printed
```

Comment: this fixed a similar issue I had with a callback function and a framework...
Thank you very much, this should be marked as a solution.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly the kind of pattern I was looking for that fits my use case, thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

If `x` is an attribute of some object, rather than a global variable, this is very simple: add a [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) method:

```
class MyType:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'x':
            self.x_callback(value)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Obviously there are ways you can make this more flexible:

- Add a way to register conditions dynamically instead of just always calling `x_callback`.
- Make it a mixin class that can be attached to any other class letting you `register(name, callback)` whatever you want.
- Combine the above, so you can `register(name, condition, callback)`.
- `self.x_callback(oldval=self.x, newval=value)` so the callback can see old and new values.
- `if self.x_callback(value):` so the callback can accept or reject the change.
- `value = self.x_callback(value)` so the callback can override the change.