# Detect global variable update to run a function every time it happens

Tags: python

I have a function that uses global variable and the second function that updates this variable. Let it be:

```
def function_1(global_var):
    print(global_var)

def function_2():
    for some_variable in function_from_another_file:
        global global_var
        global_var = some_variable
```

function_2 basically gets some_variable that is *yielded* from yet another function in another file.

The thing is that global_var is sometimes updated few times a second and sometimes every x seconds, it isn't repetitive time period at all.

For now Im using :

```
While True
```

to run function_1 as frequently as possible, but I'm looking for a way to run it every time global_var is updated (changed). How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm assuming you're running these in different threads / processes? You can use other objects from those modules to communicate when the update happens, `threading.Event` for instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback on variable change in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885246/callback-on-variable-change-in-python)

Comment: Your design choice here makes this difficult. Don't rely on global variables, instead pass state explicitly as arguments to functions or use a class to handle your state.

Comment: You can use `theading.Lock` place two locks one before the var and one after and just toggel them or use `signal` [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) to start the other function each time the value changed.