# Python 3, how use global variable with tkiner Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm trying to make a combobox with tkinter with an example as below

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

choosen_place = ""

def main():
    global choosen_place
    window = Tk()
    window.title("online")
    window.geometry("400x250")
    input_mesto = Label(window, text="choose workstation:")
    input_mesto.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def choose_place(event=None):

        global choosen_place
        choosen_place = mesto.get()
        print(str(choosen_place))

    mesto = StringVar()
    workstation = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    combo = Combobox(window, state = "readonly", values = workstation, textvariable=mesto)
    combo.grid(column=1, row=0)

    combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', choose_place)
    Label(window, text="choosed workstation " + choosen_place).grid(column=0, row=1)


    window.mainloop()
main()
```

why the variable "choosen_place" is not displayed in the label?

Comment: Because when the first time you run this code,the variable `choosen_place` is `''`(its length is zero but it is a string).You can add `print(choosen_place)` before the `Label(xxxxx` to see the variable `choosen_place`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback on variable change in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885246/callback-on-variable-change-in-python)