# Is it possible to run a function when a variable is updated without using a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing some code in Python for a project of mine where I need to write a variable to a file whenever the variable changes, which I have managed to do by utilizing a while loop and storing the previous state of the variable and comparing the two, which is fairly resource intensive. Which made me think about how with Arduino's there is the [`attachInterrupt()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) command which runs a function when it detects that the input on a pin has changed. e.g.

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(5), your_function, CHANGE);
```

Which when the input on digitalPin 5 changes, it runs the function `your_function()`.

So I was wondering if there was anything similar for Python or if I would need to stick with my loop to detect changes.

Comment: You're looking for a callback function implementation. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51885354/2681662

Comment: @MSH Thank you, I was unaware that callbacks existed and I could modify my code to use them.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as duplicate